# Array Says Its Length Is 0 But Console Says Otherwise

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, console

Good Afternoon,
I have encountered a problem with my code:
I have a for function adding values to an array variable but whenever I run the page it gives me an error stating that the array is empty. Here's the code adding values to the array:

```
    if(this.Type === "Image") {
        this.Frames = [];
        for(var i = 0; i <= Sources.length - 1; i++) {
            var Img = new Image();
            Img.src = Sources[i];
            this.Frames["Frame" = i] = Img;
        }
    } else {
        this.Frames = [];
        for(var i = 0; i <= Sources.length - 1; i++) {
            this.Frames["Frame" + i] = Sources[i];
        }
    }
```

The code runs fine. How do I know that? Well I went on the JavaScript console and checked what value the array had. It said Frames[0], but when I collapsed it, it had Frame0, and when I collapsed that, the source it had was the correct source. So, what is going on with this? Is it a glitch or am I doing something wrong that I didn't know of before? 
Thanks in advance.

[image: This is what comes up on the console]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because JavaScript only has *numeric* arrays.  It does ***not*** have associative arrays.

When you do: `this.Frames["Frame" + i] = Sources[i];`, what you are doing is adding a *property* to the array (in JavaScript, everything is an object, and can therefore have properties).  You are not actually *pushing* to the array.

One thing you can do is use an object instead: `this.Frames = {};`.

Or, you can `.push()` onto the array and use it as a numeric array.

```
this.Frames[i] = Sources[i];
// or
this.Frames.push(Sources[i]);
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, stupid mistakes. I used an Object before I did an array and it would give me an error because I would have to specify the frame name. What I did is that I forgot to take out the "Frame" + i from it which treated it as an Object. Thanks though, all this writing gets to you once in a while which causes dumb mistakes that you don't realize.

Answer (score 0):

The `.length` property of JavaScript arrays only counts properties whose names are strings that look like integers (like "0", "1", etc).  You can add whatever properties you want to an array instance, but only numeric properties affect the length of the array.